# How to crop against a plot in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I came across a code in matlab which plots a rectangle in an image. I want the image to be cropped at that rectangle.How can I do this?
I don't have much knowledge about matlab so any help would be appreciated.
Here's the code:

```
img = im2double(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/iS2Ht.jpg'));
BW = im2bw(img);
imshow(BW)
dim = size(BW)
col = round(dim(2)/2)-90;
row = min(find(BW(:,col)))
boundary = bwtraceboundary(BW,[row, col],'N');
imshow(img)
hold on;
ti = plot(boundary(:,2),boundary(:,1),'r','LineWidth',3);
```

> Unfortunately I cannot upload the image.See the red rectangle drawn in the image when you run the code. I want to crop it against that rectangle.How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the minimal and maximal range of you rectangle like this:

```
r = [min(boundary) , max(boundary)];
```

And then crop the image with these values:

```
img_cropped = img(r(1) : r(3) , r(2) : r(4) , :);
imshow(img_cropped)
```

Bonus tip: adding a `;` at the end of the lines will hide the output.

Comment: hey thanks for the help. It works fine but I just discovered that my code above doesn't work for all images. Can you tell me how to crop an image inside a black box like the one in this link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/iS2Ht.jpg

Comment: Your code works for that image, so I cannot tell you how to modify it for your other images. You should open a new question (possibly marking this one as solved?), providing examples of other images where your code does not work.

Comment: ok will do. please post an answer to that question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: hey can you please give me advice on this..... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45750323/how-to-identify-and-crop-a-rectangle-inside-an-image-in-matlab