# How to identify and crop a rectangle inside an image in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have an image which has a rectangle drawn in it. The rectangle can be of any design but the background isn't a single color. It's a photo taken from a phone camera like this one.
[image: Test image]
I want to crop the to inner picture (scenary) in the image.

> How can I do this in MATLAB?

I tried this code

```
img = im2double(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/iS2Ht.jpg'));
BW = im2bw(img);
dim = size(BW)
col = round(dim(2)/2)-90;
row = min(find(BW(:,col)))
boundary = bwtraceboundary(BW,[row, col],'N');
r = [min(boundary) , max(boundary)];
img_cropped = img(r(1) : r(3) , r(2) : r(4) , :);
imshow(img_cropped);
```

but it works only for one image, this one
[image]

and not the one above or this one

[image]

> I need to find a code which works for any image with a specific rectangle design.Any help will be aprreciated.Thank you

Comment: Does your image always have one color background?

Comment: No, actually its one color but its sort of a gradient color as you can see in the last image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The processing below considers the following:

- backgroung is monochrome, possible with gradient
- a border is monochrome(gradient), is easily distinguishable from background, not barocco/rococco style
- a picture is kind of real world picture with lots of details, not [Malevich's Black Square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Square_(painting))

So we first search the picture and flatten background by entropy filtering

```
img=imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMBRg.jpg');
%dimensions for neighbourhood are just a guess
cross_nhood = false(11,11); cross_nhood(:,6)=1;cross_nhood(6,:)=1;
img_ent = entropyfilt(img./255,repmat(cross_nhood,[1 1 3]));
img_ent_gray = rgb2gray(img_ent);
```

Then we find corners using Harris detector and choose 4 point: two leftmost and two rightmost, and crop the image thus removing background (with precision up to inclination). I use r2011a, you may have a bit [different functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/detectharrisfeatures.html), refer to MATLAB help

```
harris_pts = corner(img_ent_gray);
corn_pts = sortrows(harris_pts,1); 
corn_pts = [corn_pts(1:2,:);...
            corn_pts(size(corn_pts,1)-1:size(corn_pts,1),:)];
crop_img=img(min(corn_pts(:,2)):max(corn_pts(:,2)),...
             min(corn_pts(:,1)):max(corn_pts(:,1)),:);
corn_pts(:,1)=corn_pts(:,1) - min(corn_pts(:,1));
corn_pts(:,2)=corn_pts(:,2) - min(corn_pts(:,2));
corn_pts = corn_pts + 1;
```

An here is a problem: the lines between the corner points are inclined at a bit different angle. It can be both problem of corner detection and image capture (objective distortion and/or a bit wrong acquisition angle). There is no straightforward, always right solution. I'd better choose the biggest inclination (it will crop the picture a little) and start processing the image line by line (to split image use Bresenham algorithm) till any or most, you to choose, pixels belongs to the picture, not the inner border. The distinguishable feature can be local entropy, std of colour values, specific colour threshold, different methods of statistics, whatever.

Another approach is to do colour segmentation, I like most Gram-Shmidt orthogonalization or [a*-b* color segmentation](https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2011/02/04/more-on-segmenting-in-a-b-space/). However, you'll get all the same problems if image is skewed and part of a picture matches the colour of a border (see last picture, bottom left corner).